# What will be the best data model for membership based websites?

Tags: database-design

I am building a paid membership based website where user can signup for different kind of membership. Membership will essentially enable or disable certain pieces of functionality in the website. A user can upgrade his membership.

What I am looking for is a datamodel that will capture the

- Payment information
- Any upgrades done
- Next Due dates

etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [free data models at databaseanswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) for inspiration.

Once you've attempted something yourself, we can help fine tune it.

Answer (score 2):

What framework/language are you using? The .NET framework has an awesome out of the box membership api that is easily expandable.

Comment: Some of the things that the OP is asking for aren't handled by ASP.NET membership - in particular the billing aspects, but the ASP.NET model is pretty easy to expand while letting .NET worry about the authentication piece.